# Strange website behaviour - GET parameter with a specific value is causing the website to redirect to 403

Tags: php, apache, joomla, phpmyadmin

I have a website running `Joomla!` (it's not mine, so I don't know how exactly it is constructed).

I've encountered a very strange problem: when I'm using the `phpMyAdmin` and I want to edit an entry in a table - I get an error `403`. If I copy the link location of the button `Edit` and place it in a new tab - I get the same. By trial and error I found out, that if I replace the `where_clause` GET parameter's value's part `%60id%60` with anything else (`%60foo%60` or `id`, for example) - everything works as expected.

Do you have any ideas, what could cause such weird behavior? Why `id`? Why is it so special?

P.S. `%60` stands for `

Comment: Smells like a website/webapp firewall like http://www.modsecurity.org/ blocking the request.

Comment: @ScottSaunders phpMyAdmin - the latest, 3.5.1, but that's not relevant

Comment: @hakre you think that's some kind of anti-SQL-injection technique?

Comment: No, not I think that, but the webapp firewall "thinks" so. A so called false positive.

Comment: Ok, since I don't have the access to the CP, gonna have to use an alternative. Chive, I guess...

Comment: Just a guess in the dark here - but does the Joomla install have a plugin that "protects" the database by adding .htaccess files throughout the site which look for urls that would modify the database structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost every time I've found this strange behaviour there was some sort of security mod in the server, either at [web server level](http://www.modsecurity.org/projects/modsecurity/apache/) or at [PHP level](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/). Hosting providers are often not even aware of it, perhaps because it's a default component of their control panel.

Your only chance is probably to find out what exact module there is and read the documentation to determine whether you can change the settings.

Comment: Thanks for some specific examples! I don't have any problems now (using Chive), but if I will - I'll try to investigate further and post results here.